# Restrict Jetty to accept requests from a whitelist of hosts

Tags: jetty

I intend to run a Jetty server (for generating PDF files with PDFreactor) on a dedicated (virtual) machine; I don't want to have it on my webserver.

According to the PDFreactor documentation, the Jetty server must run on localhost to be usable by the Python API; but a port and host can be given to the `PDFreactor` constructor, and apparently the restriction to listen to localhost *only* can be lifted.

Can Jetty be configured to accept requests from some whitelist of hosts only, or is it preferable to put it in a VirtualHost and let apache httpd do the work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting IP addresses for Jetty and Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924102/restricting-ip-addresses-for-jetty-and-solr)

Comment: @Andy Lester: Yes, you're right.