# Jetty/Solr IP whitelisting and authentication

Tags: solr, jetty, solr4, solrcloud

I am using Solr 4.8.X and need help getting around https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4470
(Basic HTTP auth for SolrCloud nodes)

Is there a way to white-list certain ip addresses in Jetty 8/Solr so that they do not require basic http authentication? I have setup an auth-constraint under security-constraint in webdefault.xml, but that affects all users irregardless of IP address.

I would like to set it up so that the IP addresses of other Solr nodes do not have to go through basic http authentication while every other ip address does.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924102/restricting-ip-addresses-for-jetty-and-solr