# How can I Control IP Access for Jetty 8.1.5

Tags: jetty

I want to make the Webpage be hidden for not permitted IP user.
So that makes them do not know even the webpage exists.

Only permitted IP user can access the Webpage.

Are there any options in the Jetty v8.1.5 to setting like above?

I try to find the way but I cannot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restricting IP addresses for Jetty and Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924102/restricting-ip-addresses-for-jetty-and-solr)

Comment: I already read that but I don 't know how to adjust to my webpage source.